# Error: 'maxbibnames' must be greater than or equal to 'minbibnames'

Tags: biblatex

Has anybody ever got this error? I'm using overleaf, and although it doesn't affect compiling I don't understand what causes it and how to fix it.

```
See the biblatex package documentation for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help. ...                                              
l.31 \begin{document}
'maxbibnames' must be greater than or equal to 'minbibnames'.
```

The line that gives rise to the error is in fact "\begin{document}".

At the same line I also get the following error:

```
See the biblatex package documentation for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help. ... 
l.31 \begin{document}
'maxsortnames' must be greater than or equal to 'minsortnames'.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have set inconsistent parameters in your biblatex style, but as you have only shown  a fragment of an error message, and not shown any code it will be hard to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only showed the help text which follows an error, not the error message itself which always starts with `!`

Presumably something like

```
! Package biblatex Error: Conflicting options (maxbibnames/minbibnames).

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 \begin{document}
                    
? h
'maxbibnames' must be greater than or equal to 'minbibnames'.
? 

! Package biblatex Error: Conflicting options (maxsortnames/minsortnames).

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 \begin{document}
                    
?
```

Which is produced by

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[maxbibnames=2,minbibnames=4]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

As  the error states, the maximum value (2 here) must be larger than the minimum (set to 4 here)

The  options may be set in other ways than on `\usepackage` `biblatex` checks at `\begin{document}` that things are consistent, which is why that line is shown as the error location, not the line where these values are set.